# Haml: for whom is it?

Tags: html, css, ruby, haml

In professional development different people make code for web applications and HTML for views. First are programmers and second are HTML markup developer with basic programming skills, but with good skills of Photoshop/etc.
I have asked some of HTML developers: did they try Haml? I showed it to them and they replied that it's an awful tool.

For Whom is this tool? For HTML developers? Or just for programmers who have to make HTML on their own without HTML developers?
What is the advantage of using it for HTML developers?

Comment: Because it has no advantages over HTML for them, but they should to rewrite existing code (snippets).

Comment: Personally I am a programmer, I work in the ruby on rails framework all day, and I hate haml. I am the one that writes most of our html. And as for the issues that haml tries to solve, modern IDE's solved those years ago... It is not hard to write clean easy to read HTML, it's just that most people don't... and adding one more layer of abstraction is not going to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia entry for Haml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml) does a good job of explaining the problems that Haml tries to solve. In short, it allows for more readable, less verbose markup by enforcing indentation, reducing repetition, etc.

It's probably more useful for a programmer who's using it inside of a framework like Rails, which will automatically take care of converting the Haml markup to HTML in the context of a web application.

A designer working with HTML and Photoshop might not find it worth the extra complexity it would add to their workflow.

Comment: Actually the example of Haml code is not equivalent to HTML code: Haml example has code blocks (each) and HTML example has not (but it may has them using any template engine). Except this, Haml and HTML code is similar excluding closing tags in HTML.

Comment: That example isn't showing how to write the same page in both HTML and Haml; it's showing the HTML that will be generated when the Haml markup is processed.